# TemplateDoesNotExist at / boards/home.html

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm creating my first site with Django and following a tutorial. [Tutorial here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/11/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-2.html).

The trouble I'm having is when attempting to load the site using the standard http://127.0.0.1:8000/, I get the error

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
boards/home.html
```

Django says it's trying to follow this path: "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Development\myproject\myproject\boards\templates\boards\home.html (Source does not exist)"

When I put that path directly into my file explorer it loads the file with no issues.

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from boards import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And my views.py:

```
from .models import Board

def home(request):
    boards = Board.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'boards/home.html', {'boards': boards})
```

And settings.py has 'boards' (the name of the app) under the INSTALLED_APPS heading.

My file structure is like so:

[image]

I hope somebody can help. Just ask if I've missed anything.

Comment: Please add the photo with a good resolution

Comment: However your template location should be `myproject->boards->templates->boards->home.html`

Comment: @mhhabib Ah sorry, I don't have enough reputation to embed an image yet. Yep, that's exactly where the file is, and exactly where it seems Django is looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think board directory should be under "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Development\myproject", not under "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Development\myproject\myproject". Here is my Django project structure.

```
.
├── README.md
├── core    <-- "board" in your project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── core
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── core
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── scan_system    <-- "myproject" in your project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
```

Comment: That's basically the structure of mine, too, it's just all wrapped in another folder that contains the main project folder, and the virtual envelope folder

Comment: OK, so how about the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py? Did you add your application?(Maybe board.apps.BoardConfig)

Comment: I have 'boards', but I'll try board.apps.BoardConfig. On the error page traceback I can see the actual data that it's trying to display, it just can't seem to load the template despite the file existing in the exact place that Django says it's looking. I wonder if it might have something to do with permissions? Or are there cases where Django can see the file but can't utilize it due to some other issue?

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models. I have an experience that my application cannot find the template file, because I did not register application to the project's settings.py.

Comment: Hmmm, when I do that, Django doesn't even try to look for the template directory. 'boards' gets it to at least look, but 'boards.app.BoardsConfig' doesn't.